# ShouldStopExecution code breaking codepen on deployment

Tags: javascript, html

I have a pen that works fine in codepen.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/qBbdydR

When I try and deploy this code to a codepen project or surge, the carousel breaks and doesn’t display the pictures.

I have isolated three lines of code causing problems:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < base.$items.length; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
 for (var i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) break;
 for (var i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(2)) break;
```

I have tried commenting out the if clause:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < base.$items.length; i++);// {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
```

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/rNxVrOO

But the carousel pics still don’t appear on a surge, or in a codepen project.

If I copypaste the code to another pen, the slider will work for 5-10 seconds, but when I refresh the page, the pics disappear.

How can the pics be appearing for only a few seconds?

Comment: Debugging on codepen is difficult why don't you copy in you local system and debug?

Comment: I could try doing that.